# React to "Out of Office" status in Skype for Business

Tags: c#, lync-client-sdk, skype-for-business

The Lync 2013 SDK publishes a `ContactAvailability` property for contacts, with values as described here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.lync.controls.contactavailability_di_3_uc_ocs14mreflyncwpf.aspx

Each of the values in this enumeration is an indication of the **color** and **pattern** shown beside the contact in Lync 2013.

It seems to me that the Skype for Business 2015 client has added a new color, coinciding with an Outlook calendar entry that is tagged with "Out of Office", as seen here:

[image]

The Lync 2013 Client SDK simply returns the Free enumeration value (same as green) for this new(??) purple status indicator.

My question is, does anyone know of a way to detect when a contact's status is such that SfB would display that contact's icon with a purple "Out of Office" status indicator? I haven't been able to find any documentation on this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure from a Lync Client SDK point of view, as I haven't done much with presence in the Lync Client SDK.

In a UMCA application where you have subscribed to presence changes you get a 
[RemotePresentityNotification](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.rtc.collaboration.presence.remotepresentitynotification_di_3_uc_ocs14mreflyncuc3cr.aspx) object you can get the AggregatedPresenceState.Activity.[ActivityToken](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.rtc.collaboration.presence.presenceactivity.activitytoken_di_3_uc_ocs14mreflyncuc3cr.aspx) which will be set to the string "out-of-office" as defined in the [MS-Pres](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc431501%28v=office.12%29.aspx) spec.

I assume there will be some way to get the ActivityToken from the Lync Client SDK.  My guess would be asking for [ContactInformationType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/microsoft.lync.model.contactinformationtype_di_3_uc_ocs14mreflyncwpf.aspx).ActivityId or Activity from the [lync user presence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/jj933083.aspx).

Comment: Thanks. This was helpful in that I was not aware of the MS-Pres spec. However, neither the `Activity` nor the `ActivityId` returns the `out-of-office` value in this situation. `Activity` is "Available", and `ActivityId` is "Free".

Comment: Actually, I need to amend this. Your answer has renewed my interest in the question. While testing, I noticed at one point that my Skype for Business status in the client actually displayed "Out of Office". When I moved the mouse, though, it changed back to "Available". It turns out that SfB doesn't consider you to be "Out of Office" if you are using your PC. However, if the PC is idle for 10 minutes (default value), and your Outlook calendar shows you as "Out of Office", then `ContactInformationType.ActivityId` will, in fact, return the value `out-of-office`, as you say.